# php/mysql find&replace Using REPLACE

Tags: php, mysql

im trying to find and replace some string in all my rows in a database 
first i get all tables and loop through them and get all columns 
then i execute this query

```
           if ($column_name !== 'id')
           {
             $replcace_q = $database->query("UPDATE $table_name SET $column_name = REPLACE('$column_name','$old','$new')") or die($database->error);
           }
```

the loop is ok and i go to each table successfully 
but 
the result of executing the command is when it updates a column it replaces the content with the column name 
for example if column_name is username 
the content will change to username.

what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is good,
but there is a single silly mistake in it.

`if ($column_name !== 'id')
           {
             $replcace_q = $database->query("UPDATE $table_name SET $column_name = REPLACE($column_name,'$old','$new')") or die($database->error);
           }`

try this one and check it will work.